# iOS 13 create typical green "add" UIButton (used in Contacts and Music app) in dark mode with SF symbols and white "plus" filling

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to create the typical "add" (plus) Button used in the Contacts and Music apps using the SF Symbols font available in IOS13.
[image: Button from the Contacts app]
[image]
The code below is working fine in light mode (because in light mode the view background is already light/white). In dark mode I do not know how to fill the inner "plus" symbol with white color easily.

```
CGFloat pts=[UIFont buttonFontSize];
UIImageSymbolConfiguration* conf=[UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithPointSize:pts-4 weight:UIImageSymbolWeightMedium];
UIImage* img=[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"plus.circle.fill" withConfiguration:conf];
img = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
img = [img imageWithTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
UIButton* add=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[add setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add setTintColor:[UIColor systemRedColor]];
[add setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0 , 0, 10)];
```

produces

[image]

Comment: The plus in the plus circle fill is just a transparent hole; if that’s not what you want, don’t do that. Making a green circle with a white plus is trivial, you don’t need a symbol image to do it all for you.

Comment: I know that the transparency is responsible for the black plus... I was hoping there is an API around SF symbols easing the 'inner' fills. (btw I started with [UIButton buttonWithButtonType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd] hoping for a one liner and now it ends up doing graphics by hand...). Using plus.circle.fill I want to ensure that I don't need to adapt things if apple designers decide to shape it different. May be too much expectation...

Comment: Well if you're that set on it, you could put something white behind it, I suppose! (There is no "inner fill", that's my whole point. It is a _hole_.)

Comment: Ok. Filling the hole I'm after:-) Thanks Matt.